Are dynamic imports at runtime in the browser (ESM) possible with Svelte?
I'm updating a Svelte component/framework library (using Vite / Sveltekit) that was created using npm create svelte. I'm using the default compilation setup.
The library must be able to render internally a Svelte component. However Svelte 5 changed the way this happen and I want to preserve compatibility no matter if the application using the library uses Svelte 4 or 5.
I added in the library a condition around the version. It gives something like this:
import { VERSION } from 'svelte/compiler';

const SVELTE_MAJOR_VERSION = parseInt(VERSION.split('.')[0]);

const { html, head } = await (async () => {
    if (SVELTE_MAJOR_VERSION < 5) {
        return SSR.render({ id, initialPage });
    }
    else {
        const { render } = await import('svelte/server');
        return render(SSR, { props: { id, initialPage } });
    }
})();

return {
    body: html,
    head: [head],
};

The package import('svelte/server') doesn't exist under Svelte 4 which is why I must somehow import it conditionally/dynamically. It seems that I can build successfully if I use Svelte 5 as a dependency, however I can't build it using Svelte 4. Also, the dist files generated when using Svelte 5 are not usable under a Svelte 4 application either.
In case this is of any help, here is the output of the failed build using Svelte 4 as a dependency.
vite v5.2.11 building for production...
✓ 16 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 199ms
error during build:
Error: [commonjs--resolver] Missing "./server" specifier in "svelte" package
    at e (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:47597:25)
    at n (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:47597:627)
    at o (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:47597:1297)
    at resolveExportsOrImports (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:48287:20)
    at resolveDeepImport (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:48306:31)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:48031:20)
    at Object.resolveId (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@5.2.11_@types+node@20.12.11/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-cNe07EU9.js:47781:28)
    at file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.17.2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19778:40
    at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.17.2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:19678:28)
    at async resolveId (file:///Users/james/Projects/inertia/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.17.2/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18359:26)


Why are you not building it via the Vite plugin? The version is static, there should be no need to have anything dynamic here.

@brunnerh What do you mean? I am using the vite plugin. I'm using what npm create svelte setups automatically (Vite, Sveltekit, preprocessor, etc.) I need to support both Svelte 4 and 5 and be able to call the proper render method based on the Svelte version

The code you added is directly interacting with the compiler and it is unclear why you are doing this

@brunnerh. Maybe with full code it is easier to understand? https://github.com/jamesst20/inertia/blob/main/packages/svelte/src/lib/createInertiaApp.ts#L85 I need to call the proper render method based on if the library is called within a Svelte 4 or Svelte 5 instance because components are no longer classes when using Svelte 5 so the render method must be imported instead

Still don't understand this. If you are using SvelteKit as claimed, that would take care of rendering if it's an application. If you build a component library, it would only pre-process the source and you would still distribute Svelte files.

@brunnerh The function I sent you received as a parameter a Svelte component. The project has a "App" Svelte component and it's going to render the App component with your component passed as a parameter as a slot (child) of the App component. Inertia (the lib) is meant to be used in any project. If you are curious here is how SSR uses that method in a project demo https://github.com/jamesst20/inertia/blob/main/playgrounds/svelte/resources/js/ssr.js

That is not really a component library, it also looks more like an application framework than anything else. You are doing the rendering that is usually done by SvelteKit. That being the case, I unfortunately can't help you, since I never had to do SSR manually.

Isn't Svelte 5 backwards compatible with Svelte 4?  This would mean that you should be able to provide a Svelte 4 version and it should work with Svelte 5 too.

@JoséRamírez There are a few exceptions see https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/breaking-changes#components-are-no-longer-classes

It appears doing this will work
async function dynamicImport(modulePath: string) {
  try {
    return await import(/* @vite-ignore */ modulePath)
  } catch {
    return null
  }
}

// Somewhere 
const { render } = await dynamicImport('svelte/server');

But this wouldn't
async function dynamicImport() {
  try {
    return await import(/* @vite-ignore */ 'svelte/server')
  } catch {
    return null
  }
}


// Somewhere
const { render } = await dynamicImport();

My guess is because vite can't guess the import before it actually happens if we use a function without dynamic parameter
